# How can I select an element using its text content?

Tags: selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown which gives a list of `<li>` with child `<span>` elements having values. I need to select a child element with value "SecondElement" and click on it. The element doesn't have an id and using XPath here looks fragile. So how can I use document.querySelector to fetch this element that has the value "SecondElement". When I try the below code I get the first element.

```
document.querySelector('.c-partnerSelector__menu__list > li > p > span')
```

Below is the console output of fetching the 1st element. But I need to select the element that has "SecondElement" as the value. I cannot use index here as this elements place can change.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you control over the `<li>` elements? can you extract it to a seperate component?

Comment: CSS selector syntax provides no way to examine text node contents.

Comment: *"XPath here looks fragile"*... Why? Can you clarify?

Comment: Why do you need to use JavaScript HTML DOM API to search element, the selenium API is not sufficient to resolve your problem?

Comment: @Andersson the elements don't seem to have an ID. I can only use XPath with these super long class names. But that is fragile right? Say the classes change or their order change, then the XPath would be broken right?

Comment: @yong using this approach because of the above comment :(

Comment: No. You can simply use following XPath `//span[.="SecondElement"]` to select `span` node with required text value or `//span[contains(., "SecondElement")]` for `span` that *contains* specific text

Comment: But in this page, there are other components. They also contain "SecondElement" records in them. This could select all of them right?

Comment: OK. `//*[contains(@class, "c-partnerSelector__menu__list")]/li/p/span[.="SecondElement"]`. This means the same as your CSS selector, but select `span` with required text

Comment: Can you put this as an answer please? Seems to be a less clumsy way :)

Comment: You should post the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below XPath to fetch `span` with required text content:

```
//*[contains(@class, "c-partnerSelector__menu__list")]/li/p/span[.="SecondElement"]
```

This means the same as your CSS selector `.c-partnerSelector__menu__list > li > p > span` + predicate to examine nodes' text content

Comment: I also have a class that goes like "c-partnerSelector u-user-select--none u-padding--small u-display--flex u-align-items--center u-cursor--pointer u-position--relative u-marign-right--large" do you think its nice to use the XPath approach on this? This element has no id

Comment: XPath can be used in this case, but it'll looks awful :) `//*[contains(@class, "c-partnerSelector") and contains(@class, "u-align-items--center") and...]`. `//*[@class="c-partnerSelector u-user-select--none u-padding--small u-display--flex u-align-items--center u-cursor--pointer u-position--relative u-marign-right--large"]`, but it will not work in case class names sequence is not constant

Comment: Since align items center and everything could change, would it be safe to use just //*[contains(@class, "c-partnerSelector")?

Comment: You should use only those class names (those attributes) that do matter. Note that you can use attributes like `type`, `title`, etc in the same way: `[@title="Some title" and @type="password"]`... - it's not only about class names

Comment: Unfortunately there are no title or type elements as well. Thanks a lot for the patient explanation Andersson! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This answered the question that was originally posted, [which was](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52315525/1):

> How can I select an element using its text content with document.querySelector?

From the comments, it became clear that that wasn't hte OP's true question, though, which is well-answered by [Andersson's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315807/157247). I'll leave this, though, for those who *do* need to do it with `querySelector` or similar.

---

CSS has no "contains" selector (one was proposed, but it stalled and has never made it into the standard).

You can use `querySelectorAll`, then use `Array#find` on it to find the one with the text you want:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.c-partnerSelector__menu__list > li > p > span');
var element = Array.prototype.find.call(list, function(el) {
    return el.innerText.includes("SecondElement");
});
```

That can look a bit cleaner in ES2015+ on a modern browser that makes the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` iterable:

```
const element = [...document.querySelectorAll('.c-partnerSelector__menu__list > li > p > span')]
                    .find(el => el.innerText.includes("SecondElement"));
```

---

Having said that: In the comments on the question, [Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4549554/andersson) seems to have a good point (for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315525/how-can-i-select-an-element-using-its-text-content-with-document-queryselector/52315599#comment91578701_52315525)) about using XPath for this, if that's an option for you.

Comment: Can you give me an equivalent way to run this in the browser console?

Comment: @mayooran - You can run this code from the JavaScript code. It's just JavaScript code using the DOM. In some consoles you may not want to use `const` in that second code block, so perhaps `var` instead. But other than that (and I think that issue maybe old, I suspect it's been resolved)...