# Replacement for document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `querySelectorAll('a')` that applies to all buttons.
I only want to query select these two specific buttons that are listed as 'Know More'.
How would I do this?

Here is my code:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('a');
buttons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var totalOffsetX = 0; // X and Y COORDINATES WITH SCROLL START
    var totalOffsetY = 0;
    var X = 0;
    var Y = 0;
    var currentElement = this;

    do {
      totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
      totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    while (currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)

    X = e.pageX - totalOffsetX;
    Y = e.pageY - totalOffsetY; // X and Y COORDINATES WITH SCROLL END

    let ripples = document.createElement('buttonspan');
    ripples.style.left = X + 'px';
    ripples.style.top = Y + 'px';
    this.appendChild(ripples);

    setTimeout(() => {
      ripples.remove()
    }, 1000);
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Know More</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button">Know More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Apparently you mean links, not buttons

Comment: You don't need a replacement for `querySelectorAll` you need a replacement for the selector `'a'`. Don't blame the tool; blame the one who uses the tool incorrectly. Add a class to both anchor elements and select on that class.

Comment: `.querySelectorAll(".buttons a")`? Or is there anything even more specific you can select them by? We can't know without a representative HTML.

Comment: How about `if (btn.innerText === "...")` before you attach the event listener?

Comment: Please learn the difference between a link and a button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select an element using its text content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315525/how-can-i-select-an-element-using-its-text-content) or [How to find a DOM element by its text content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58052522/215552)

Comment: make your life simple, add a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the collection from `querySelectorAll()` to an array and use `.filter()`.

```js
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].filter((x) => x.innerText==="Know More");
       
       console.log(buttons);
       buttons.forEach((a) => { a.addEventListener('click',()=>{
       console.log("yo"); });
       });
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Know More</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button">Know More</a>
      <a href="#a">Know Less</a>
    </div>
```

Note: If you know the content of the anchor tags already('Know More'), giving a relevant class name would save you this headache. Then you can simply do :

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('a.knowmore');
```

Since the return type of `querySelectorAll()` is not exactly an array but NodeList, I am using the `...` operator to convert them into an array, to make `.filter()` method work.

`.forEach()` is a method implemented on the NodeList and that is why it works in your code. But, I found this in the docs. Probably mean Internet Explorer here.

> Some older browsers have not implemented NodeList.forEach().

Answer (score 0):

You can use the element `id` or `class` to specify which specific buttons you want to select, like

```
<a class="foo">...</a>
<a>...</a> //won't be selected
<a class="foo">...</a>
```

And then use the proper CSS selector

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.foo")...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no CSS selector that checks the contents of an element (jQuery has a `:contains()` extension, but it's not available in standard `querySelectorAll())`.

So you'll need to check for this in your loop:

```
buttons.forEach(btn => {
  if (btn.textContent.trim() == 'Know More') {
    // rest of code
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a specific class name for the elements that you want to get and then use `document.getElementsByClassName` method.

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('know-more');

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="know-more">Know More</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button know-more">Know More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to get only those elements that you need.

```
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];
const knowMoreButtons = buttons.filter(button => button.textContent === 'Know More')
```